# List index out of range when parsing a website using .lower()

Tags: python, python-2.7, nlp

I'm parsing a website in order to count the number of newlines in which a keyword is mentioned. Everything runs fine with the following code:

```
import time
import urllib2
from urllib2 import urlopen
import datetime

website = 'http://www.dailyfinance.com/2014/11/13/market-wrap-seventh-dow-record-in-eight-days/#!slide=3077515'
topSplit = 'NEW YORK -- '
bottomSplit = "<div class=\"knot-gallery\""

# Count mentions on newlines
def main():
    try:
        x = 0
        sourceCode = urllib2.urlopen(website).read()
        sourceSplit = sourceCode.split(topSplit)[1].split(bottomSplit)[0]
        content = sourceSplit.split('\n') # provides an array
        
        for line in content:
            if 'gain' in line:
                x += 1
        
        print x
    
    except Exception,e:
        print 'Failed in the main loop'
        print str(e)

main()
```

However, I'd like to account for all mentions of a particular keyword (in this case `'gain'` or `'Gain'`). In turn, I included `.lower()` in reading in the source code.

```
sourceCode = urllib2.urlopen(website).read().lower()
```

Yet this gives me the error:

> Failed in the main loop
>
> list index out of range

Supposing `.lower()` is throwing off the indices, why is this occurring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using lowercase only string (that's what `lower()` does) but you're trying to split using `topSplit = 'NEW YORK -- '` which should create a list with a single item.

You then try and access that list on index 1, which will **always** fail:

```
sourceCode.split(topSplit)[1]
```

To account for both cases take a look at regular expressions usage with the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module, here is an example:

```
>>> string = "some STRING lol"
>>> re.split("string", string, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
['some ', ' lol']
>>> re.split("STRING", string, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
['some ', ' lol']
```

Comment: Great answer, and in light of what you suggested I used `topSplit = 'NEW YORK -- '.lower()` to get it to run. I'll check out the `re` module as well, thanks for the heads up.